# Small annoyance in Visual Studio's code pretty-fier

Tags: visual-studio, coding-style

Visual Studio has a lot of great features, one of which makes your code pretty for you.
I love that and there's nothing wrong with it except for one little detail.

Coming from Java and PHP both Netbeans and Eclipse didn't do that and allowed me to develop my own style. (Though surely it's not unique)

This is how I write my methods:

```
void myMethod () {
}
```

Which is changed to:

```
void myMethod() 
{
}
```

I am totally fine with the next-line on the curly brace.

However I really don't like that Visual Studio removes the little space between the method's name and the parentheses.

Does anyone know how to specifically turn that off?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about explaining how to use a tool.

Comment: I'm sorry, would you please clarify where else I should place my question?

Comment: @Vanitas: http://superuser.com/ looks like more appropriate for this type of questions. But don't recreate one there; instead, wait for this question to be migrated.

Comment: Yes it's possible, but using your own style only serves to confuse/frustrate other c# developers who need to look at your code later. Do not use a space between the parenthesis and method names should be upper camel case `void MyMethod()`. Personally, when I have to develop in other environments I conform to the code formatting of those languages. P.s. don't embarrass yourself by trying to justify anything with PHP.

Comment: I suppose you're right, It just seems confusing having Classes and Methods using the same style.
I shall have to adapt I assume.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sort of things is configurable in Visual Studio. I believe it's in:

Tools › Options › Text Editor › C# › Formatting › New Lines

Also note that if you're developing in C#, there is an official style which is quite popular (the default set of rules of StyleCop, a style checking tool for C#). While you're free to use a different style, you may want to have a look at the official one if your intention is to:

- Distribute your code,
- Read code of other developers or:
- Work in a team.

Comment: As of yet I'm just playing around a bit to get a feel of C#. (Must say it feels a lot nicer than Java)
Thank you for not only answering my question but also sharing this information, this is useful. If I am to eventually distribute or develop in groups I will have to adapt to this style.

Answer (score 1):

> However I really don't like that Visual Studio removes the little
>   space between the method's name and the parentheses.

Tool, options, Text Editor, C#, Formatting, Spacing.

There's an option "Insert space between method name and its opening parenthesis", for both method declarations and calls.

However, you're totally wrong to like this style :-)

Comment: Or so I've heard! I will adapt to the C# way I guess, but no one will stop me from using my little space-between-method-and-parenthesis in other languages, muawhahahahahahaha

Comment: I suppose its better than the coding style one of my predecessors used - no spaces in a line at all! `if(x>y){` sigh.